# PostgreSQL combinations as distinct from permutations

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, combinations, permutation

Can't figure out how to make combinations of arrays without repetitions.

```
   INPUT is an array of n variables LIKE '{A,B,C,D,E}'
   Variable A is always single array LIKE '{"A"}' or '{"D,C"}' or '{"D,A,B"}' etc..

   What I need is to combine INPUT with A(i)

 EXAMPLE:
     1. A = '{"B"}'       --> att='{"B,A","B,C","B,D","B,E"}'
     2. A = '{"B,C"}'     --> att='{"B,C,A","B,C,D","B,C,E"}'
     3. A = '{"B,C,A"}'   --> att='{"B,C,A,D","B,C,A,E"}'
     4. A = '{"B,C,A,D"}' --> att='{"B,C,A,D,E"}'
```

As far I have this:

```
WITH A(i) AS (SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['A,B'])),
     B(j) AS (SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['A','B','C','D'])),

     cte AS ( SELECT A.i ||','|| B.j
              FROM A
              CROSS JOIN   B 
            )
     SELECT ARRAY ( SELECT * FROM cte) INTO att;
```

But it makes duplicity:

```
"{"A,B,A","A,B,B","A,B,C","A,B,D"}"
```

Comment: Since you frankly label this as a school project, you should really solve this yourself. Hint: since you are working with strings, have a look at the [string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html).

Comment: What you're looking for is exactly "combinations" as distinct from "permutations". Algorithms to do this are well documented.

Comment: ... also there are numerous existing answers if you search for "postgresql combinations" on Stack Overflow. What makes this different? (BTW, please don't build arrays using string concatenation like this; use unnest and array_agg or the `ARRAY[...]` constructor

Comment: As @CraigRinger said (and the OP in the question): use the `unnest()` function. To avoid multiple self-joins, and multiple `a.x <> b.y` clauses, you could use a recursive CTE (using `candidate_element  <> ALL( cte_array_expression_here)`  And restrict the maximum number of elements by limiting the recursion depth.

Comment: Reposted to http://stackoverflow.com/q/30515990/398670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH  RECURSIVE 

     A(i) AS (SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['A,B'])),
     B(j) AS (SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['A','B','C','D'])),

     cte AS (  SELECT j AS combo, j, 1 AS ct 
               FROM B 
             UNION ALL 
               SELECT cte.combo ||','||B.j, B.j, ct + 1 
               FROM cte, B
               WHERE ct <= 4
                AND position(B.j in cte.combo) = 0
            )
    , com AS ( SELECT A.i ||','|| B.j AS cmb
               FROM A
               CROSS JOIN B)

     SELECT ARRAY(SELECT cmb FROM cte,com where cte.combo = com.cmb)
```